# React and JavaScript

Tags: reactjs

Do we need to fully know JavaScript to study react
And what all programming languages do we need to know before learning react,
And how to proceed to react native,
Do we need to learn any other native programming language to use react native?

Comment: The short answer is No. Learn as you go.

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: Try asking google for some ES6 tutorials and some React tutorials. Try learning a little JavaScript. No, you don't need to fully know JS. But yes, you need to know something. It will be difficult for your do understand what's going on without JS knowledge. But the good news is, getting started isn't terribly difficult. Give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know fully javascript to study react native, probably you will need to understand the basics of `iOS(basically pods and Xcode)` and `Android(gradle and Android Studio and probably understanding of Java)`.

I haven't used Reactjs, react native is my first touch with the React library. so I will use my personal experience to explain what I just said.

When I started with mobile development (I haven't touched anything about Desktop development or Web development), I started with iOS, and after that, I moved to Android, and after that, in my first job, I moved to react native. With iOS and Android I learned how those platforms work, but not so much about coding.

When I moved to react native I didn't know anything about JavaScript, I took one course in Udemy, but that was basically what you can find on w3school. I took another course for React Native where I learned how to set up the project. After that, it was just about time to make projects and read the documentation.

**You can start without knowledge of the native programming languages**, but as you go deeper into React Native, you will realize that you will need to know about the native. But, it is not necessary to start with React Native.

Comment: Just like you said that we need not know about native to start react native,but when we go further and need to know native,would that be a confusing....